# Did The Temptation of Jesus happen on day 40

Tags: matthew

In the gospel of Matthew, it makes it sound in the NASB like the temptations came first after 40 days of fasting.

> **2** And after He had fasted for forty days and forty nights, He then became hungry. **3** And the tempter came and said to Him, “If You are the Son of God, command that these stones become bread.” [Matthew 4:2-3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matt+4%3A2-3&version=NASB)

Did Satan first come to Messiah on day 40?

Answer (score 2):

There is a parallel account in (NIV) Luke 4:

> 1 Jesus, full of the Holy Spirit, left the Jordan and was led by the Spirit into the wilderness, 2where **for forty days** he was tempted  by the **devil**. He ate nothing during those days, and at the **end** of them he was hungry.
>
> 3The **devil** said to him, “If you are the Son of God, tell this stone to become bread.”

Satan had been tempting Jesus all along for 40 days. Only the final three temptations were recorded in detail.

Comment: "**after** He had fasted for forty days and forty nights, He then became hungry*" satan temps Yeshua to make bread of stones but he is hungry after 40 days.

Comment: The "after" in Matt. is logically consistent with the "for forty days" in Luke. They are both true.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus, full of the Holy Spirit, left the Jordan and was led by the Spirit into the wilderness, 2where for forty days he was tempted by the devil. He ate nothing during those days, and at the end of them he was hungry.

3The devil said to him, “If you are the Son of God, tell this stone to become bread.”

Satan had been tempting Jesus all along for 40 days.

**Only the final three temptations were recorded in detail.**

The forty days for Jesus to be tempted ended on day forty.

The devil came after the forty days had ended.
the temptation period was over!

Thus I consider these temptations to be not temptations at all but direct spiritual messages to Jesus from the devil as he was skeptical about Jesus' divinity.

2 where for forty days he was tempted by the devil. He ate nothing during those days,
**and at the end of them he was hungry.**

Jesus, as a human being in all things like his brethren, was hungry after 24 hours, never mind 40 days!!!

Thus, the above scripture is not a reference to Jesus' human state at all, but a reference to his divine spiritual state as the Messiah, the Son of God!

Jesus fasted not only as the Son of Man, a human being without food but also as the Son of God without the power of the spirit while being in the desert. A power that Jesus could only use for the glory of the Father amid humans, at that precise moment in time satanic, mortal, and spiritually dead. By using the power of the spirit, Jesus would have used it for his glory while being tested in the desert.

Jesus as the Son of God was not just hungry but starving for the truth, justice, and to fulfill the Father's will and work.

3 The devil said to him, “If you are the Son of God, tell this stone to become bread.”

In the first message above, the devil made it clear to Jesus, that if He is the Son of God, the Messiah, and came into this world to acquire the human heart, the bread for Jesus,  at that moment in time of stone, the bread for Satan by his presence within, He, Jesus must turn the human heart of stone back into flesh. this is well asserted in

Ezekiel 36:26 And I will give you a new heart, and put a new spirit within you: and I will take away the stony heart out of your flesh, and will give you a heart of flesh.

Notice, that the last part says:

and I will take away the stony heart...

Now the stony heart is a reference to Satan's heart of stone at that moment in time within the human heart. Then in the first part it says:

And I will give you a new heart, and put a new spirit within you:

The new heart is a reference to Jesus, as a spirit, the Son of Man, "THE WORD" made flesh, in the human heart through redemption on Jesus' death, Luke 17:20-37